# ReferenceError: firebase is not defined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase

I designed a login(through firebase) page. After successful login I want to access home Page.but it shows this error(ReferenceError: firebase is not defined) in terminal.According to my Opinion the error is in firebase databse initialization.Any one please help me to get rid of this error.

Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="bg-dark">

    <div id="login-card" class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h1>Wallpaper App Admin</h1>
            <form id="login-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control"   />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button id="btn-login" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script>

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
            if(user){
                window.location.href = "admin.html";
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my admin.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <h1> You are Logged in!!! </h1>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

    <script>
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
            if(!user){
                window.location.href = "index.html";
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "API-key",
authDomain: "e-agriculture9.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://e-agriculture9.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "e-agriculture9",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: "1086965307452",
appId: "1:1086965307452:web:ea0fd9076744c723a5cb39"
};
 // Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL; 

 $("#btn-login").click(function(){


     alert("You Clicked here!");

   var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val(); 

    var result = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    result.catch(function(error){
        var errorCode = error.code; 
        var errorMessage = error.message; 

        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage);
    });

});
```

Here is my DEBUG CONSOLE:

```
c:\Users\hp\Desktop\WallpaperAppAdmin\public\js\app.js:11
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
^

ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\hp\Desktop\WallpaperAppAdmin\public  \js\app.js:11:3)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:14)

ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\hp\Desktop\WallpaperAppAdmin\public \js\app.js:11:3)
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:14)
```

According to Debug console these are the critical lines of code in app.js file:

```
 firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL;
```

When I add Import statement at the beginning of app.js file it shows in debug console:

```
Debugger attached.
c:\Users\hp\Desktop\WallpaperAppAdmin\public\js\app.js:1
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

Please guide me how to edit these lines of code to get rid of this error.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a heads-up with the `apiKey` in your post, if this the real key, having it publicly visible will cause you misfortune.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to import firebase, you cannot use firebase without importing it.

if you are using node/express use: npm i firebase , then import firebase in your app.js.
then this error will be gone.

```js
import firebase from 'firebase'
var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyDjmzbv8ebrz_oEctHiwor84wlhLPXJKoI",
authDomain: "e-agriculture9.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://e-agriculture9.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "e-agriculture9",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: "1086965307452",
appId: "1:1086965307452:web:ea0fd9076744c723a5cb39"
};
 // Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL; 

 $("#btn-login").click(function(){


     alert("You Clicked here!");

   var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val(); 

    var result = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    result.catch(function(error){
        var errorCode = error.code; 
        var errorMessage = error.message; 

        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your sincere attention. Your Suggestions works for me perfectly.